# Tableviewcell collapse and open while scrolling the tableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitableviewrowaction

Can any one please refer the @RetailMeNot application home screen which has the very nice animation, where the tableview cell will collapse and open with the scroll, Is there any SDK to do that similar part of animation. Thanks in advance...

This link will give clear idea how the tableview cell will expand while scrolling..

https://dribbble.com/shots/1713915-Gestural-Scroll-Interaction

Comment: Can you post the appstore url?

Comment: App store link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/retailmenot-coupons/id521207075?ls=1&mt=8  refer home screen